# How to check if geth node is running ,from web3j code

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

I am connecting to Geth using Web3j plugin.

`web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://<ip>:<port>"));  // defaults to http://localhost:8545/`

However, if the Geth node is not started, I need to throw an exception. How can I find if the Geth node is started or no using web3j java code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("LINK-TO-YOUR-NODE"));
    // this will cause the exception if web3j is not connected
    LOG.info("Connected to Ethereum client version: "
        + web3j.web3ClientVersion().send().getWeb3ClientVersion());
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("WEB3-Connection Error", e);
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

The answer of TLHBM is also correct

Answer (score 1):

```
web3j.netVersion().send().getNetVersion();
```

this code is getting blockchain chain ID(version)

we can use this kind of code for checking a connection

from [this](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/docs/source/smart_contracts.rst#specifying-the-chain-id-on-transactions-eip-155)

Answer (score 0):

RPC net_listening is available to check if provider is available (specifically over IPC where connection does not mean that RPC is available).

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#net_listening

Web3j exposes this as netListening method.

```
web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://<ip>:<port>"));
if(web3j.netListening() ){
//Do rest of operations 
}
```